# Error: Could not find or load main class com.build.test.Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Error: Could not find or load main class com.build.test.Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.build.test.Application

That's it. The program worked, then I updated the program to a new dependice at Spring boot and then it stopped working.
I restarted the update and tried the old version, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling maven.

If you update a dependency, you may need to reinstall maven as well.

```
mvn install
```

Or look there it is well described
[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: That should work otherwise look at the link.

Comment: Okay, fine. I had a similar problem. it was bad. because I found nothing.